# How to upload unique file. Jmeter distributed testing

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have a scenario where I have to upload a unique named text file.I have used counter in the thread level and using the reference name as file name.say If I want to upload the File_1.txt, I have used something like this `file_${counter_refname}`.This is working like a charm in single machine but, Now the problem is when I run in the distributed mode slave_1 is uploading the File_1.txt and Slave 2 machine is also uploading the same file File_1.txt.  The Target server will not allow to upload file with same name. How to resolve this problem??

Answer (score 0):

Use a CSVData Set that will contain file names.

Create 1 file per distributed node referenced by it and ensure all these files never contain the same file name.

To do it, first create 1 file with unique names then split it in as many files as you have nodes.

Another option is to just generate a unique file name if sequence number is not important by using __UUID function:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__UUID

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple of functions which can help to identify slave machine and parametrize file name.

- [__machineName()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineName) - returns hostname of machine running JMeter instance
- [__machineIP()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineIP) - the same for IP address

Also you can look into [__Random()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) or [__RandomString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString) functions to generate unique files with random names on the fly i.e. with [Beanshell PreProcessor](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) as follows:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
String filename = "file_${__Random(10000,99999,)}.txt";
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File(filename), "a quick brown fox", "UTF-8");
vars.put("filename", filename);
```

Refer to generated file name as `${filename}` where required.